# Show and hide 2 buttons with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a table with many table rows. Every row has a button "Add" with unique id given for that record. When I click the button an ajax request is send and on succes i need to hide this button and show the other button "delete".

Here is the code:

```
    foreach ($this->routes as $route) {
    echo '  <tr>
                <td> <span class="label label-info">' . $route->id . '</span></td>
                <td> ' . $route->fromLocation . '</td>
                <td> ' . $route->toLocation . '</td>
                <td> ' . $route->startRoute . '</td>
                <td> ' . $route->endRoute . '</td>
                <td style="text-align:center;"> <span class="label label-important"> ' . $route->distance . '</span></td>
                <td class="show" id="' . $route->id . '" style="text-align:center;"> <i class="fa fa-binoculars" </td>
                <td> 
                    <button type="button" id="add'.$route->id.'" style="width:100%;" class="btn btn-success btn-mini"
                    data-route="' . $route->id . '" data-transire="' . $this->transire[0]->id . '">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus-square fa-fw"></i>' . $this->translate('Add') . '
                    </button> 
                    <button type="button" id="delete'.$route->id.'" style="width:100%;" class="btn btn-danger btn-mini"
                    data-route="' . $route->id . '" data-transire="' . $this->transire[0]->id . '">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus-square fa-fw"></i>' . $this->translate('Add') . '
                    </button> 
                </td>
            </tr> ';
```

And js:

```
        $('.btn').click(function() {
        alert($(this).attr('id'));

        var routeid = $(this).data("route");
        var transireid = $(this).data("transire");

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/transire/addroute',
            data: {routeid: routeid, transireid: transireid},
            beforeSend: function() {

            },
            complete: function() {

            },
            success: function(response) {
                  // hide this button
                  // how to show the delete button here ????
            }
        })
    });
```

Well I am not sure if i am on the right track here. Basicly i want to get the id of the other button and show it. But how to access it ? Thank you !

Comment: Both of your button has text: `$this->translate('Add')`

Comment: FYI, you'd have better to just delegate click event to TABLE level and filtering event target from there instead of setting so many handlers for all buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your css, make a style for classes `hidden`:

```
.hidden{display:none;}
```

And in jquery:

```
var id=this.id.replace(/\D+/,'');
$("#add"+id).addClass("hidden");
$("#delete"+id).removeClass("hidden");
```

The `replace(/\D+/,'')` replaces all non-numeric characters with empty strings, thus removing all non-numeric characters. However, this only works if the id is numeric, which I assumed.

Instead of adding and removing a class, you could also toggle them with `toggleClass("hidden")`

Comment: It works ! Thanks ! What is this replace(/\D+/,''); ?

Comment: The replace(/\D+/,'') is to remove all non-numeric characters from a string (in this case the id). Therefore, you end up with only the number.

Answer (score 1):

**The simple way**

First add an extra class in the delete button, let's say 'delete-button' so your button becomes:

```
<button type="button" id="delete'.$route->id.'" style="width:100%;" class="btn btn-danger btn-mini delete-button" data-route="' . $route->id . '" data-transire="' . $this->transire[0]->id . '">
    <i class="fa fa-plus-square fa-fw"></i>' . $this->translate('Add') . '
</button>
```

At the place that you have this comments:

```
// hide this button
// how to show the delete button here ????
```

You can put:

```
$(this).hide();
$(this).parent().find('.delete-button').show();
```

The first line of the new code is clear what it's doing, just hiding the pressed button.
The second line, first finds the parent element of the pressed button, then finds the element with class 'delete-button' and then it shows it.

**Another way, using the ids instead of a class**

Change the ids of your elements to have a dash in between, instead of:

```
id="add'.$route->id.'"
id="delete'.$route->id.'"
```

Make it

```
id="add-'.$route->id.'"
id="delete-'.$route->id.'"
```

This will result to something like this (for route id = 5000):

```
id="add-5000"
id="delete-5000"
```

The in your success method you can do:

```
$(this).hide();
var routeId = $(this).attr('id').split('-').pop();
$('#delete-' + routeId).show();
```

Here we took the id of the current button (add), then split the it with the dash resulting to an array with 2 elements, first the text "add" and second the route id. Then we pop the route id and we use it to find the delete button element.

Comment: Thank you! I messed up my question a bit. Each button fires a different ajax post with the same parameters. So maybe I need to add to the buttons onclick='Add(this)' and for the delete button  onclick='Delete(this)' and then in each function to show/hide the opposite button.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `context` option to `$.ajax()` method then you could easily target specific row:

```
$.ajax({
    context: this, //< context set on clicked button
    type: "POST",
    url: '/transire/addroute',
    data: {
        routeid: routeid,
        transireid: transireid
    },
    beforeSend: function () {

    },
    complete: function () {

    },
    success: function (response) {
        $(this).add($(this).closest('tr').find('.btn-danger')).toggle();
    }
});
```

***Question:*** do you really need all these IDs in HTML?!

Comment: Thanks for the help ! Yes I need them. Why are you asking ? Is it a bad practice ?

Comment: Setting useless attributes in DOM is never a good idea, so that's why i was asking.

Comment: Why there are useless ? I need those params. Is there other solutions to pass them ?

Comment: @LubomirBorisov If you need them for some reason at backend, **then** they are NOT useless, that was what i meant ;)